# Unable to ping hostname only IP address

Tags: networking, windows, dns, ping, hostname

I'm trying to connect to my linux server via the hostname for Samba. I'm have been able to access it with no problem then all of a sudden it stopped working. Here is what is happening.

This is what I have done from a windows PC

- Can ping the IP
- Can NOT ping the hostname
- Can do nslookup and it finds the hostname
- Can traceroute IP and resolves the hostname
- Can ping other things on my network by hostname
- If I add the IP and hostname to the hosts file on my windows PC I can ping the hostname just fine. When I rebooted my router the issue persisted. (From 1st Line Supports answer)

From the Ubuntu 14.04 server

- Can ping self by IP and hostname
- Typing "hostname" resolves appropriate hostname
- Can ping other things on my network

Here is my /etc/hosts file

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1       servername
>
> # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
>
> ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>
> fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>
> ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
>
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

My DNS server is my router which does dhcp and dns via dd-wrt.
Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the firewall?

Comment: yes, my firewall has this IP open.

Comment: Test another computer.

Comment: I can't ping or access it from any of my computers, tablets, fireTVs, phones, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the entry for your hostname and IP address in to the /etc/hosts
If it works, then it is probably DNS try rebooting the router and remove the entry you have just added.

Comment: I added the IP and hostname to the local hosts file and I was able to ping via the hostname. I will try rebooting my router now.

Comment: I rebooted my router and I can not ping the hostname.

Comment: That would appear to be a DNS issue with the router, which is off topic, but as a pointer, look for your FQDN i.e. <host.domain>, some routers add a default domain entry to the hostname or keep the entry in the hosts file or run DNS from Ubuntu

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that I found the issue in my router.